# Efficiency of converting MySQL result to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I use a MySql backend to store data that we use in a single page angular app.  We send down and store data from the server in IndexedDB inside Chrome.  We have quite a few tables of information but particularly there is one that has about 20k entries with close to 300 fields.  When we initially developed the platform, we ran a standard SQL query and then we iterated over the result to build a JSON statement to return.  This process would take about 35 seconds so we've been looking to improve this.  I have since been testing with more of the specific JSON tools within MySQL, like json_array and json_arrayagg.  What I found is I've gone from a very fast select statement with a slow process of iteration to a very slow select statement that doesn't require iteration.  In all, there were no improvements to the time it was taking.  Is there a more efficient process I could be using to speed this up?  For reference, the iteration is done in PHP in case there is something that could be used there.

Ok, editing to address some comments.  We are delivering this amount of data to the client.  We actually have several tables of this size and we utilize ag-grid on the front end so users can filter, sort, group, etc.  So we load all of the data locally on login and provide a speedy environment after that initial load.  That initial load is what I'm looking to improve.  For a little more context, one of these tables is a product database.  Our users will go to the database and may filter by any of the available fields.  The options to filter by are generated by the data already in the grid.  This is just one example but long story short, we need the data local.

I measure the timing by logging time stamps around the sql statement as well as the before and after a while loop that processes the result of the sql.

Delivery back after the JSON has been created is minimal (a few seconds).

We actually build the sql statement dynamically based on the module that we are running it on but for reference, here is how the select is built.  The large module would obviously list every field:

```
$select = " SELECT json_objectagg(json_object(
                 'docType' VALUE 'EXOAD_BidGroup',
                 'date_modified' VALUE exoad_bidgroup.date_modified ABSENT ON NULL,
                 'name' VALUE exoad_bidgroup.name ABSENT ON NULL,
                 'deleted' VALUE exoad_bidgroup.deleted ABSENT ON NULL,
                 'id' VALUE exoad_bidgroup.id ABSENT ON NULL,
                 '_id' VALUE exoad_bidgroup._id ABSENT ON NULL,
                 'isChanged' VALUE '0')) ";
```

The original process was a basic select statement and then we iterated over the result with the following to piece together the JSON before returning it:

```
while ($row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($dbResult)) {
                $id                        = $row['id'];
                $singleResult              = array();
                $singleResult['docType']   = $module;
                $singleResult['_id']       = $row['id'];
                $singleResult['isChanged'] = 0;
                $parentKeyValue            = '';
                if ($isHierarchical == 'Yes') {
                    if (isset($row[$parentModuleKey]) && $row[$parentModuleKey] != ''){
                        $parentKeyValue = $row[$parentModuleKey];
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value !== null && trim($value) <> '' && $key !== 'user_hash') { //put this in tenant utils
                        $singleResult[$key] = html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES);
                    }
                }

                $result_count++;
                if ($isHierarchical == 'Yes' && $parentKeyValue != '') {
                    if (!isset($output_list[$module . '-' . $parentKeyValue])) {
                        $GLOBALS['log']->info('hier module key -->> ' . $module . '-' . $parentKeyValue);
                        $output_list[$module . '-' . $parentKeyValue] = array();
                    }
                    $output_list[$module . '-' . $parentKeyValue][$id] = $singleResult;
                } else {
                    $output_list[$id] = $singleResult;
                }
            }
```

Let me know if I can provide any other details.

Another Edit...

The time is definitely spent inside the foreach Loop within the while statement.  I don't have the exact number but the entire process would drop to seconds without that foreach.  But...that is how the data is getting formatted into JSON so any ideas on speeding that part up would be what I'm looking for.  MY guess is it doesn't exist but it would be nice if there was some php function that could take each result row and transform the data into json without iterating over every field.

Comment: You're delivering 20,000 rows * 300 columns worth of JSON to the client?

Comment: Are you measuring only the generation of the JSON, or are you also measuring the delivery? What is your MySQL to JSON pipeline look like, are you using a DTO or plain old arrays?

Comment: It can be anything, you should post your code

Comment: It's impossible to say from your description where the bottleneck is. Is it the PHP code? Could the PHP code be written more efficiently? Probably. But you haven't shown the code so no one can make a suggestion for improving it. Regardless, it's going to take some time to prepare such a large result set no matter what.

Comment: Do you really need to fetch that massive amount of data in one go? Why not just fetch the data you need, when you need it? That would be the most efficient. You also say that you iterate through the data, is there a reason for that? What exactly is it you do when you iterate through it? You could just convert the whole result to json without adding your own iteration. But as others have said, we need more details here (like your code etc)

Comment: You should also add how you benchmarked the code to determine where the issue is

Comment: I would comment out the `foreach` and benchmark just the `while` loop. This should get you a measure of the 20,000 rows. If that is closer to your full benchmark, you might need to optimize the transport or the query itself. You could also just run the `while` loop without any internal logic to get an even more raw view of that.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas after seeing the code I posted last week or any other info I could provide?

Answer (score 1):

A well-indexed table can be searched for desired rows much faster than downloading all rows, then filtering in the app.

Comment: This is good to know but the entire function of the app is built on having all of the data in a single grid.  Filtering aside, the grid automatically subtotals and counts specific columns similar to how Excel would so data needs to be available regardless of a filter.  I appreciate you taking the time to comment.

Comment: @BrettBloch - Databases are efficient even for billions of items because they have techniques to avoid having to look at every item.  On the other hand, spreadsheets and JSON essentially require tedious scans of everything; hence there are limited to thousands of items.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are primarily escaping quotes here. Have you tried using the `QUOTE()` function in mysql as part of your query?

You can see if this helps as part of your select statement. Check out [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quote-function-in-mysql/) for how you could use this.

Then maybe you can just comment out that `foreach` loop and just run `json_encode()` on the result of your `while` loop.

I'd be curious to see if this works for you, and if it has any performance improvements. Let me know.